# Ionic - ion-input has a blank space in front even after it is cleared

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

Im using the latest version of **Ionic 2**.

I have an `ion-input` inside a component. The placeholder and the type are passed into component.

```
<my-component placeholder="Add some text here" type="text"></my-component>
```

In the component HTML,

```
<ion-input placeholder="{{placeholder}}" type="{{type}}"></ion-input>
```

The placeholder shows and when I type something in it gets removed as it should.

[image]

So that works great. But the problem is, when I have completely erased the text I typed in. When the last letter is cleared the focus is set to after the first letter of the place holder like on the image below. When I hit backspace again, the focus moves to the front of the placeholder.

[image]

Have I done something wrong? Is there a workaround I can try for this?

Comment: is the cursor in the right place initially (before you type anything) ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa yes. it's in the right place initially.

Comment: Seems like a vague problem. Do you have any link to your app where I can check & debug, Its tough to point out otherwise?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Only on iOS though. It works fine in UIWebView but might be an issue with WKWebView if you're using that. Will investigate this too.